# How can I access a JSON payload in Slim framework?

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest, slim

I am developing a RESTful web service using Slim framework and PHP. At the moment I have been able to send a JSON payload post request, (which I also parsed back as response... just for testing). How do I access the values of the JSON payload after decoding it?

```
 public static function processAuth(){
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $body = $request->getBody();
    $user = json_decode($body);


    echo json_encode($user);
}
```

Comment: Do a var_dump($user) to see the contents.

Comment: i used var_dump() and its contents were returned....my question is how do i access and assign each value to a string variable. thanks

Comment: Depends on contents of $user. For example $foo = $user["foo"]. 

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

Comment: @MikaTuupola, i have tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

By default `json_decode()` returns an object.
You need to turn on associative return to be returned, using the second argument.

```
$user = json_decode($body, 1);
print_r($user);
```

Comment: This is indeed the right answer to the problem OP suggested. In addition, it is worth mentioning that for an `stdClass` object returned by `json_decode`, you can always access its properties with the syntax: `$user->foo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case $user will be an associative array, so to acess the variable's values of the decoded json you have to call it like this: $user['variableName'].

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you post what appear when you var_dump($user) and also when you echo json_encode($user)? That way I can take a look.